# How to select radio button in selenium webdriver ? dynamic select of radio button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td>
<input id="nodeAccountOid" type="radio" onclick="setNodeAccountIdToCredentialCheck('E9E2930C4493B569E040A8C0158E4ABD');" style="width:100%;border:0px">
</td>
<td>E9E2930C4493B569E040A8C0158E4ABD</td>
<td>monacho1</td>
<td>urn:dece:org:org:dece:dece:cs</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td>
<input id="nodeAccountOid" type="radio" onclick="setNodeAccountIdToCredentialCheck('E9E2930C4494B569E040A8C0158E4ABD');" style="width:100%;border:0px">
</td>
<td>E9E2930C4494B569E040A8C0158E4ABD</td>
<td>monacho1</td>
<td>urn:dece:org:org:dece:coord:cs</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td>
<input id="nodeAccountOid" type="radio" onclick="setNodeAccountIdToCredentialCheck('E9E2930C4495B569E040A8C0158E4ABD');" style="width:100%;border:0px">
</td>
<td>E9E2930C4495B569E040A8C0158E4ABD</td>
<td>monacho1</td>
<td>urn:dece:org:org:dece:300</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td>
<input id="nodeAccountOid" type="radio" onclick="setNodeAccountIdToCredentialCheck('E9E2930C4495B569E040A8C0158E4ABD');" style="width:100%;border:0px">
</td>
<td>E9E2930C4495B569E040A8C0158E4ABD</td>
<td>monacho1</td>
<td>urn:dece:org:org:dece:10</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i want to select the radio button corresponding to urn:dece:org:org:dece:10 which is fourth row in the html provided. the row may change sometimes based on some inputs in AUT. please provide me the way to select it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Well what changes? Is it always `urn:dece:org:org:dece:10`?

Comment: @Arran : the urn:dece:org:org:dece:10 never changes but its position may chage.i want to select it accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the text never changes, you can use that as a starting point within the DOM, and use XPath to navigate through to the `input` you need:

```
//td[.='urn:dece:org:org:dece:10']/parent::tr/descendant::input[@id='nodeAccountOid' and @type='radio']
```

1. Get the `td` that has it's `text` **equal to** `urn:dece:org:org:dece:10`
2. Get that `td`'s parent `tr`
3. From that parent `tr`, get the `input` that has an `id` **equal to** `nodeAccountOid` and has a `type` of `radio`.

Therefore it doesn't matter where **exactly** the elements are, as long as the XPath locator can navigate up to the `parent` and back down again to the `input` you need.

Comment: the xpath you sent worked like a charm. thanks a lot and thanks for explaining the Steps too :
)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is to locate a certain element in the web page that may occur in different positions. 
If there is another element which can be identified easily by its content, id or name and there is a static relation between this element and the one you would like to locate, then you could use xpath. There are also some examples for this in the selenium documentation as far as I know.

Comment: i want to traverse along urn:dece:org:org:dece:10 row and Select the radio button irrespective of its position in page. can you please provide me a xpath to select that radio button. i have used the below xpath to select radio button which is at 4th row driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='nodeAccountOid'])[5]")).click();